# Ignite(2.3.0) not getting started on windows

Tags: windows, ignite

I have downloaded binary release of ignite(2.30),also i have JAVA installed.Sample program from Eclipse is getting executed successfully however w I am getting below error when I  start Ignite from command line :

```
G:\Apache Ignite\apache-ignite-fabric-2.3.0-bin\apache-ignite-fabric-2.3.0-bin>CD %IGNITE_HOME%/bin

G:\Apache Ignite\apache-ignite-fabric-2.3.0-bin\apache-ignite-fabric-2.3.0-bin\bin>ignite.bat %IGNITE_HOME%/example
s/config/example-ignite.xml
Error: Could not find or load main class Ignite\apache-ignite-fabric-2.3.0-bin\apache-ignite-fabric-2.3.0-bin\libs\
*;G:\Apache\*
Error: Could not find or load main class Ignite\apache-ignite-fabric-2.3.0-bin\apache-ignite-fabric-2.3.0-bin\libs\
*;G:\Apache\*
Error: Could not find or load main class Ignite\apache-ignite-fabric-2.3.0-bin\apache-ignite-fabric-2.3.0-bin\libs\
*;G:\Apache\*
ignite.bat, WARN: Failed to resolve JMX host. JMX will be disabled.
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to create Ignite component (consider adding ignite-spring module to
 classpath) [component=SPRING, cls=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:966)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:350)
        at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:302)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to create Ignite component (consider adding ignit
e-spring module to classpath) [component=SPRING, cls=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl]

        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteComponentType.componentException(IgniteComponentType.java:320)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteComponentType.create0(IgniteComponentType.java:296)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteComponentType.create(IgniteComponentType.java:207)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.loadConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:671)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:874)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:783)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:653)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:622)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:347)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteComponentType.create0(IgniteComponentType.java:282)
        ... 8 more
Failed to start grid: Failed to create Ignite component (consider adding ignite-spring module to classpath) [compon
ent=SPRING, cls=org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl]
Note! You may use 'USER_LIBS' environment variable to specify your classpath.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 2):

Issue resolved , I renamed G:\Apache Ignite to G:\ApacheIgnite (no space).

Comment: I have filed [IGNITE-7233](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-7233) about this.